# Netbeans 7 Swing not working

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I had a gui (swing) project developed using netbeans 7 and JDK 6. Then I've installed JDK 7 and project still worked fine. But then I've reinstalled netbeans and now when I open my project it says that "swing-app-framewok" library is missing. Also I'm unable to create new swing application - there is no such item in menu.
Can I make my project work again?

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 if it's important.

Comment: Have you tried looking for a Netbeans Swing module or plugin, and installing it on your new Netbeans?

Comment: @mindmaster find (HDD) where is saved this file and import that to the Libraries folder in your project, nothing special, that's happends when you change ClassPath,

Comment: @VicentePlata thanks, I even didn't think that it can be disabled (it actually was)

Comment: Was your problem fixed mindmaster? Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vicente Plata was right, I just needed to enable Swing plugin.